# Pattern-match in function literal

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Give a pattern-matched anonymous function:

```
val a = List((1,2), (3,4))
val c = a.map{case (x, y) => (y, x)}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing as a function literal using some similar syntax?

```
val f = case (x,y) => (y,x)
val c = a.map(f)
```

Something better than this:

```
val f = (z: (Int, Int)) => {
  z match {
    case (x, y) => (y, x)
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you adding `.`s between `map` and its arguments?

Comment: @pedrofurla sorry, typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you type annotate and surround in {}:

```
scala> val f: (Int,Int) => (Int,Int) = { case (x, y) => (y,x) }
f: (Int, Int) => (Int, Int) = <function2>
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks.